# Как упростить условие конструкции if

Tags: javascript, функции, if

Необходимо по заданию упростить условие if

```js
let a = 1;
if (!(a == 1 || a == 15)) {
 console.log(a);
} else console.log("No");
```

Comment: Что значит упростить?

Comment: `if( ! [1, 15].includes(a) )` - тоже может быть удобно, если есть несколько значений - исключений)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let a = 1;
if (a != 1 && a != 15) {
 console.log(a);
} else console.log("No");
```

Comment: Это упрощение? :)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Это они неправильно назвали. Задание на преобразование (раскрытие скобок) булевских выражений.

Comment: о_О Да вы телепат 80 уровня! Или уже сталкивались с подобными заданиями? Или... Хмм... Возможно, это стандартное задание по предмету "Логика"?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Это я догадался :). Посмотрим, что будет.

Comment: @Igor Ставки принимаете ?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Ставки принимаете ?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko  не проблема если вариант Igor  не пройдет значит это Ваш вариант :)

Comment: какие тут ставки могут быть? 100 к 0, что задача на логические выражения.

Comment: @teran "Петя готов был держать пари – между прочим, пари тоже категорически запрещалось, ..." Катаев "Белеет парус одинокий"

Answer (score 0):

Можно цифры `1` и `15` положить в массив и проверять вхождение через метод [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). При этом из первоначального варианта убрать отрицание и просто поменять блоки `if` и `else` местами . Если `a` содержится в массиве - вывести `No`, иначе вывести это число.

```js
let a = 1;
if ([1, 15].includes(a)) {
  console.log("No");  
} else console.log(a);
```

Но и это еще не всё, можно сделать запись короче используя тернарное выражение `?:` внутри `console.log` вот так:

```js
let a = 1;
console.log([1, 15].includes(a) ? "No" : a);
```